# How to check-in for a Royal Wings flight in Brussels?

Tags: transit, tickets, bru, charter, royal-jordanian

My friend is going from London via Brussels to Aqaba (LHR-BRU-AQJ). BRU-AQJ being on a Royal Wings flight.

He's going hand-luggage-only.

What I wonder is:

1. Can he check in online for Royal Wings flights?
2. Can he collect his connecting boarding pass in the transit area at BRU?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Charter flights are not usually included in the airlines booking or online check in system.  They are normally private flights set up for the chartering company.  Your friend would likely get the best answer from the organizer as they know what special arrangements have been made.

Comment: Difficult to know. Almost by definition, the flight must have been chartered by someone and your friend would have bought the ticket from them. What are they saying?

Comment: @Relaxed They aren't responding to his e-mails or phone calls. He booked through http://www.prijsvrij.nl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He should use regular (online) check-in of the airline, using papers received 7 days before departure, according to the website where you booked. (translated from dutch):

http://www.prijsvrij.nl/veelgestelde-vragen/voor-vertrek/inchecken-and-stoelreservering